# $P(X_1+X_2<0)=???$

Tags: probability

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be random variables i.i.d  $\mathcal{N}(2,5)$. What is $P(X_1+X_2<0)$?

My attempt:
**X**$=X_1+X_2$ has distribution $\mathcal{N}(4,10)$

$P(\textbf{X}<0)=0.3446$

Is it correct?

Comment: If one of the answers below is satisfactory, consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark button next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

$P(X_1+X_2<0)=P\left(\frac{X_1+X_2-4}{\sqrt{10}}<-4/\sqrt{10}\right)\\=\frac12-P(0<Z<4/\sqrt{10})\\\approx0.5-0.3962\\=0.1038.$

Answer (score 0):

Your thought process is correct but your calculation is not.

If $5$ is the *variance* of each $X_1$, $X_2$, then the sum $X = X_1 + X_2$ has variance $10$ as you wrote.  But then the correct probability is $$\Pr[X < 0] = \Pr\left[\frac{X - 4}{\sqrt{10}} < \frac{0 - 4}{\sqrt{10}} \right] \approx \Pr[Z < -1.26491] \approx 0.102952.$$  If $5$ is the standard deviation, then the standard deviation of the sum is $\sqrt{5^2 + 5^2} = 5 \sqrt{2} \approx 7.07107$, and then $$\Pr[X < 0] = \Pr\left[\frac{X - 4}{5 \sqrt{2}} < \frac{0 - 4}{5 \sqrt{2}}\right] \approx \Pr[Z < -0.565685] \approx 0.285804.$$  Which calculation you intend depends on whether $5$ is a variance or a standard deviation, but you cannot mix them up as you have done.